# Unable to send mail from Laravel 4 on godaddy hosting

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I am using the following code to send email using Laravel 4.

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', array('data' => 'This is a test content' ), function($message)
{
    $message->to('mymail@site.com', 'TomTom')->subject('Welcome to Laravel!');
});
```

whenever I try to send an e-mail, it throws the following error:

```
A connection could not be established with the host 
smtpout.asia.secureserver.net [Connection refused #111]
```

But when I send e-mail using the **php mail** function, it works fine!

```
var_dump(mail("mymail@site.com", "subject", "hello world"));
```

Then what is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide how you have set your email up in Laravel 4 under mail.php with out password. else I would suggest you to use Mailgun or ManDrill services, less headache.

Comment: @maytham here is mail.php http://pastebin.com/PYLNjmeE

Comment: see not able to find a solution yet, I will vote up so maybe other can come with ideas.

Comment: @Cody You have no username/password in that config. Did you censor them, or is it blank? Try switching the driver to `mail` (which is what `mail()` uses) or `sendmail`.

Comment: Change `'driver' => 'smtp'` in `config/mail.php` to `'driver' => 'sendmail'` or `'driver' => 'mail'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try another port:

```
return array(    
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'ailstore1.asia.secureserver.net',
    'port' => 465,
    'from' => array('address' => 'mail@mysite.in', 'name' => 'name'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',   
    'username' => '',    
    'password' => '',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false
);
```